# include 'wp_enqueue_scripts' (CSS) to multiple templates

Tags: templates, wp-enqueue-script

5 of my templates require specific Javascript. Currently the below works great to load Javascript into Page Template A.

```
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','css-flags');
  function css-flags(){
  if ( is_page_template('page-template-a.php') ) {
   wp_enqueue_style('css-flags', get_template_directory_uri() . 
   '/css/flags.min.css', array(), '1.0.0', false );
  }
 }
```

I thought that I could simply do the following to add the same CSS file to Template B, C and D by just adding the template name to the 'IF' variable.

```
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','css-flags');
  function css-flags(){
  if ( is_page_template('page-template-a.php','page-template-b.php','page-template-b.php') ) {
   wp_enqueue_style('css-flags', get_template_directory_uri() . 
   '/css/flags.min.css', array(), '1.0.0', false );
  }
 }
```

Thanks for all direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page template seems like a more obscure thing to base the loading of your CSS on. Maybe not use template name, and use page name instead as it's more apparent to theme users. If interested you could try something more like this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_special_page_styles');
function load_special_page_styles() {
    global $post;

    if( is_page() ) {

        switch( $post->post_name ) { // post_name is actually the page slug            
            case 'a-page': // if page slug is equal to 'a-page'...              
            case 'b-page':
            case 'c-page':
            case 'd-page':
            case 'e-page':
                wp_enqueue_style( 'css-flags', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/flags.min.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all' ); // Note slight differences in use of wp_enqueue_style here
                wp_enqueue_script( 'js-flags', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/flags.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true ); // helpful param #2 loads jquery if not already loaded, and param #4 loads the flags.min.js script in the footer, after page content loads
                break;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: wow...! Very interesting...I'm going to test this out and ill report back

Comment: Can the same be applied for Javascript? I guess the answer is yes - but just want to be sure..!

Comment: You're right! Also it is recommended to [load css and js scripts together in the same function](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#combining-enqueue-functions) using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook.

Answer (score 1):

`is_page_template` accepts a single argument, which can be a string or an array. You just need to pass your values as a single `array()` to make it work:

```
if ( is_page_template( array('page-template-a.php','page-template-b.php','page-template-b.php') ) ){
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, `||` is the OR operator so you have to build it that way feeding `is_page_template()` a single template so your conditional will look like this:

```
if ( is_page_template('page-template-a.php') || is_page_template('page-template-b.php') || is_page_template('page-template-c.php') ) {
     // Code Here
}
```

Comment: thanks @cedon and milo > interesting to see which one is 'more accepted'. I like the sound of the array but they both seem to be able to do exactly the same thing...

Comment: @henry functionally they will achieve the same end goal, but one call to `is_page_template` with an array of values will be slightly faster than calling `is_page_template` for each value(i.e. multiple calls to function).